# Ruby 1.9 hash with a dash in a key

Tags: ruby, syntax, hash, ruby-1.9

In ruby 1.9 is there a way to define this hash with the new syntax?

```
irb> { a:  2 }
=> {:a=>2}

irb> { a-b:  2 }
SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
{ a-b:  2 }
      ^
```

with the old one, it's working:

```
irb> { :"a-b" =>  2 }
=> {:"a-b"=>2}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Ruby 2.2, you also can use following syntax:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, 'c-c': 3, d: 4}
```

Comment: awesome! +1 for updating with the new ruby syntax, from which version is available? 2? 2.1?

Comment: I don't know, i just tried this syntax and it had worked :)

Comment: @makevoid new syntax is available since 2.2:  https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#language-changes

Comment: @EddyMulyono +1

Answer (score 64):

There are some legitimate symbols that cannot be used with the new syntax.  I cannot find a reference, but it appears that a symbol name matching `/^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*[!?]?$/` is allowed with the new syntax.  The last character may be the special character "!" or "?".

For any symbol that does not meet these restrictions, you have to use the Ruby 1.8 syntax, `:'my-symbol-name'`

Comment: Which makes sense; how is the Ruby interpreter supposed to read that, otherwise?

Comment: I checked in `parse.c` and it seems that with the new syntax the symbol is parsed as `tLabel` token. And matching name is more like /[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]/ :-)

Comment: @MBO, Extra points for going to the source.  I've edited the regex in my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @prusswan - I can't imagine a purist programming in Ruby.

Comment: In Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.0, passing ```data: { my_attr: 'foo' }``` to a helper method like ```button_tag``` will produce ```data-my-attr="foo"``` in the rendered HTML

Comment: ? and ! are also also valid characters if they are the final characters before the colon. Similar to method names. So this is valid: `{a: 1, b?: 2, c!: 3}`

Comment: @ChrisBeck the same thing works with Ruby 2.0 and Rails 3.2, e.g. `data: { my_attr: 'foo' }` -> `data-my-attr="foo"`.

Answer (score 24):

You can combine the old and new syntax:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, :'c-c' => 3, d: 4}
```

Answer (score 24):

To use dashes with the new syntax:

```
<%= link_to "Link", link_path, {data: {something: 'value1', somethingelse: 'value2'}} %>
```

This will generate:

```
<a href="/link" data-something='value1' data-somethingelse='value2'>Link</a>
```

This might not exactly be your particular use case, but I found this post while trying to find an answer myself so I thought I'd share my findings.

Comment: AFAIK, this is specific to the `data` attributes, if you have other attributes with dashes you have to use the old syntax.

Comment: The [HAML documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html5_custom_data_attributes) mentions data attributes separately. As a bonus, you can get multiple dashes by using underscores: `data: {author_id: 123}`. Great stuff.