# How to escape a dash "-" in a Ruby symbol?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery-mobile with Ruby On Rails.

I want to create a button link which implies to have `data-role="button"` appear in the generated HTML.

I've tried:

```
<%= link_to "Play", game_play_path, :data-role => "button" %>
```

But then, I get an error

```
undefined local variable or method `role' for #<#<Class:0x007fdc25668ee8>:0x007fdc25658610>
```

Is there a way to escape the dash using the `:xxx` notation or should I just use the `"xxx"` notation?

(I agree it's a cosmetic question, but I want my code to be consistent and don't like exceptions)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use single quotes around the symbol name, with the colon prefix:

```
:'data-role' => 'button'
```

And here is a nice reference on symbols:

http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm#_What_do_symbols_look_like

After `Ruby 1.9` you can also do

```
'data-role': 'button'
```

Comment: Or double quotes - either works fine. Also note that you [can't use a symbol escaped in such a way with the 1.9 alternative hash syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134702/ruby-1-9-hash-with-a-dash-in-a-key)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I voted for the most complete answers but all the contributions were welcome! :)

Comment: As a habit, I usually use double quotes for when there will be string interpolation, and single for when the string ought to be immutable.

Answer (score 15):

If you find the syntax `<%= link_to "Play", game_play_path, :"data-role" => "button" %>` ugly because it uses the old hash syntax, another way to do it that involves using ruby 1.9 syntax for hashes is to do the following:

```
<%= link_to "Play", game_play_path, data: {role: "button"} %>
```

The hash imbrication generates the hyphen between data and role in the html output.

Be cautious because this only works with data-something attributes, but in your case it's a more eye pleasing alternative.

Also, if you have more data-something attributes, you can write them as well in the nested hash:

```
<%= link_to "Play", game_play_path, data: {role: "button", other1: "value1", other2: "value2"} %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in single quotes:

```
:'data-role' => "button"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to "Play", game_play_path, :"data-role" => "button" %>
```

Comment: Or alternatively use a straight string `"data-role"`. No need for it to be a symbol. #codegolf