# Can I use html tags in twitter-bootstrap popover data-content?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap within a Rails 3.1.3 application. I have numerous elements with popovers like:

```
<a data-original-title="Quality" rel="popover" data-content="Did they do a good job?  5 for Really Nice, 4 for Good Enough, 3 for Average, 2 for Somewhat OK, 1 for Really Bad">Q</a>
```

I'd like to have an ordered list in the content section similar to:

```
<OL reversed="reversed">
  <LI> for Really Nice </LI>
  <LI> for Good Enough </LI>
  ...
</OL>
```

Is there a simple way to do this without modifying the JavaScript? Whatever I try, the html code is displayed on the browser instead of being interpreted as such.

**UPDATE**

Using the following code per David's suggestion

```
link_to 'Q', '#', options: { data-original-title: "Quality", rel: 'popover', data-content: "Did they do a good job? <ol><li> for Really Nice </li><li>...</li></ol>".html_safe }
```

generates a syntax error with my setup. I think this explains why: [Ruby 1.9 hash with a dash in a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134702/ruby-1-9-hash-with-a-dash-in-a-key) . So I'm using:

```
<%= link_to 'Q', '#', options: { :"data-original-title" => "Quality", :rel => 'popover', :"data-content" => "Did they do a good job? <ol><li> for Really Nice </li></ol>".html_safe } %>
```

This doesn't work. It generates the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" options="{:&quot;data-original-title&quot;=&gt;&quot;Quality&quot;, :rel=&gt;&quot;popover&quot;, :&quot;data-content&quot;=&gt;&quot;Did they do a good job? &lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt; for Really Nice &lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;&quot;}">Q</a>
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to create a popover instance that has the `html` option enabled (place this in your javascript file after the popover JS code):

```
$('.popover-with-html').popover({ html : true });
```

Then the link syntax would be:

```
<%= link_to('Q', '#', :class => "popover-with-html", :title => "Quality", "data-content" => "#{some_content_object.html_safe}") %>
```

If you're dynamically generating the content, then you need to use `html_safe` like David suggested so Rails doesn't escape the HTML code.  Otherwise, you can just place HTML directly within that content attribute.

Comment: With this solution HTML options are correctly passed. However HTML is still not interpreted for data-content. This is what Firefox shows: <a href="#" class="popover-with-html" data-content="Did they do a good job? &lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt; for Really Nice &lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;" data-original-title="Quality" rel="popover">Q</a>

Comment: Works fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It looks like Rails is escaping the HTML before it gets to JS with the above syntax. The following works with "html : true " option set: <a data-original-title="Speed" rel="popover" data-content="Did they get the work done quickly?
           <OL> <LI> 5 for Really Fast </LI> </OL>
           ">S</a>

Comment: You didn't say you were dynamically populating the `data-content` in your original post.  In that case, then yes you do need to use `html_safe` when you render the content attribute.  Next time, please be sure you give your exact code instead of giving pseudo code.  See my answer update

Comment: Why isn't this in their documentation?

Comment: @nilskp File an issue with them on GitHub if you think it should be.

Comment: @iWasRobbed, in a perfect world I would.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but you need to call `html_safe` on your string (if the string is generated by Rails)

```
link_to 'Q', '#', :title => "Quality", :rel => 'popover', "data-content" => "Did they do a good job? <ol><li> for Really Nice </li><li>...</li></ol>".html_safe }
```

Comment: Thanks David! I tried your suggestion and I think it's the right path. However, "data-original-title" and "data-content" are not valid HTML attributes that can be passed to link_to. "title" works instead of "data-original-title". I can't find anything that works instead of "data-content" though. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to pass them within an `options` hash. See my updated answer.

Comment: With Ruby 1.9.2 your code generates a syntax error. I had to use <%= link_to 'Q', '#', options: { :"data-original-title" => "Quality", :rel => 'popover', :"data-content" => "Did they do a good job? <ol><li> for Really Nice </li><li>...</li></ol>".html_safe } %> instead. This is not working either though. The HTML generated is: <a href="#" options="{:&quot;data-original-title&quot;=&gt;&quot;Quality&quot;, :rel=&gt;&quot;popover&quot;, :&quot;data-content&quot;=&gt;&quot;Did they do a good job? &lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt; for Really Nice &lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;&quot;}">Q</a>

Comment: Let me know if you're still having issues. If it's working, can you mark the answer as accepted so that future users can find the answer to their question easily ?

Comment: No problem, iWasRobbed. Your solution is clearly the correct one (and I've upvoted it). I just feel that questions with answers should be marked as solved, since it makes searching for solutions easier. OP, please mark iWasRobbed's answer as correct.

Comment: Nevermind, Arman did not specify in the OP that the content was dynamically generated so you were correct about `html_safe`.