# How to generate markup inside of <xsl:attribute> text?

Tags: xslt

My XSLT stylesheet generates [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) HTML where some elements may contain `data-...` attributes to pass additional data to the framework. For example, I have this code to generate a [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) element:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true">
    <xsl:attribute name="title">Popover Title</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="data-content">This is some additional content.</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:text>Link</xsl:text>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

The `data-content` attribute is supposed to contain additional markup. The resulting output should be something like

```
<a href="#" ... data-content="This is <em>some</em> additional <a href='#'>content</a>.">Link</a>
```

How do I generate markup text for the `<xsl:attribute>` in this case?

(Somewhat related: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202762/html-inside-twitter-bootstrap-popover) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494291/can-i-use-html-tags-in-twitter-bootstrap-popover-data-content) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-div-as-content-for-twitters-popover).)

**The answers**

Thanks for the answers! While I think that [kjhughes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398651/how-to-generate-markup-inside-of-xslattribute-text#28399342) provides the technically correct solution to implement properly what I need, I think that [Ian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398651/how-to-generate-markup-inside-of-xslattribute-text#28399742) addresses my question more directly.

Comment: I don't think unescaped markup is allowed within an attribute's value, is it? It most certainly isn't if your output is XML.

Comment: Right, it is not.  See [details below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28399342/290085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put unescaped markup in an attribute value, but [you don't need to](http://jsfiddle.net/gr5qweku/4/) - if you escape the angle brackets (and any ampersands and quotes-within-quotes) as entity references bootstrap will still render the html properly in the popover.

```
<a href="#" data-content="This is &lt;em&gt;some&lt;/em&gt; additional &lt;a href='#'&gt;content&lt;/a&gt;.">Link</a>
```

The simplest way to get this right in the XSLT would be to use a CDATA section:

```
<xsl:attribute name="data-content"
  ><![CDATA[This is <em>some</em> additional content
    &amp; a <a href="#">link</a>.]]></xsl:attribute>
```

And the serializer will escape it for you as necessary.

Comment: Interestingly, the fiddle worked partially: the `<em>` doesn't show but the `<a>` does.

Comment: @Jens so it does, I tried changing em to strong and that does come out bold so it only appears to be certain tags. Or maybe it's something in bootstrap's css.

Comment: @Jens ok, it's jsfiddle's fault - [here's a version with "normalize css" unticked](http://jsfiddle.net/gr5qweku/4/) which renders the `em` as expected.

Comment: And to make this just a little more funky, I can use several `CDATA` sections to wrap other XSLT elements. For example: `<xsl:attribute name="data-content"><![CDATA[<a href="#" id="]]>popup-<xsl:value-of select="@id"/><![CDATA[">Link</a>]]></xsl:attribute>`

Answer (score 0):

***You cannot generate markup inside of an `xsl:attribute` because XML does not allow unescaped markup inside of attributes.***

Specifically, the [grammar rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue) for `AttValue` prohibits `<` altogether and `&` unless the `&` is part of a properly formed `Reference`:

```
AttValue       ::=      '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'
                      | "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
```

Supporting definitions:

```
Reference      ::=      EntityRef | CharRef
EntityRef      ::=      '&' Name ';'
CharRef        ::=      '&#' [0-9]+ ';'
                      | '&#x' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ';'
```

HTML too, even [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attribute-value), does not allow unescaped markup in attribute values.

Adding escaped markup in attribute values is viable but ugly.  Especially for heavily marked-up content, I'd recommend creating the content separately and then associating it procedurally via JavaScript rather than declaratively via attribute values.  There are many examples of doing this, including [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26408903/290085) mentioned in one of your references.

Comment: I believe the HTML spec is more pertinent here, as that's what OP is generating:  "*The attribute value may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45), periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons (ASCII decimal 58).*" http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Hm. Are you saying that Bootstrap's use of the `data-content` attribute is invalid HTML?

Comment: @Jens Can you point to an example where they use markup inside the `data-content` attribute? I haven't seen one on the page you linked to.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I just added references to three other questions, all of which have examples of HTML embedded into that attribute (in particular [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202762/html-inside-twitter-bootstrap-popover) one).

Comment: @Jens I am not an expert on HTML, but IMHO that is **not** valid HTML. Even if it *may* work (in *some* browsers). Note that at least one of the answers you linked to says the same thing expressly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8908888/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thank you. Considering that, the better (more compatible?) way to attach HTML to the popover's body seems to be Javascript instead of using the `data-content` attribute.

Comment: @Jens I don't think the actual method by which you populate the attribute's value is of the essence; what matters here is the result, i.e. what ends up as the contents when the page is rendered.

Comment: @Jens, yes, I prefer [**this approach**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26408903/290085) from your first example, especially when you need a lot of markup.  Besides markup not belonging in attribute values for XML or HTML, separate `divs` are easier to create, read, and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Not an "official" way of doing this, but when using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to process the XML and XSLT stylesheets, consider using [*XSLT extension elements*](http://lxml.de/extensions.html#xslt-extension-elements) in your stylesheet. Those custom elements allow you to run Python code when elements match during processing, and that code can modify/edit parts of the output document.