# unexpected tLBRACE

Tags: ruby, hash

This is probably one line answer fot Ruby pros. I am getting syntax error:

```
unexpected tLBRACE  at line 1
```

I believe this is closely related to the issue in [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134702/ruby-1-9-hash-with-a-dash-in-a-key) but I am not able to figure whats wrong in my case.

Could some please pin point whats the issue ?
Thank you for your time.

```
def user_profile_picture(user,  size: [50, 50], type: :square, style: 'img-polaroid', opts: {})
    tag :img,
        { width: ("#{size[0]}px" if size),
          height: ("#{size[1]}px" if size),
          src: facebook_profile_picture(user, type),
          alt: '',
          class: [('verified' if user.class == User.model_name && user.facebook_verified?), style].compact.join(' ')
        }.merge(opts)
  end
```

ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

****Stack trace****

```
 SyntaxError - /Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...er_profile_picture(user,  size: [50, 50], type: :square, sty...
...                               ^
/Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
..._picture(user,  size: [50, 50], type: :square, style: 'img-p...
...                               ^
/Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...:square, style: 'img-polaroid', opts: {})
...                               ^
/Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
        }.merge(opts)
         ^
/Developer/rails-workspace/roommate/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:127: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end:
  app/helpers/users_helper.rb:7:in `'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
```

Comment: `tag :img,` must go inside the hash

Comment: now it says "unexpected tLABEL"

Comment: @Sudhakar It would be good if you post also the stack trace. Here also mention line#1 means which statement.

Comment: @RubyLovely - I meant the beginning of the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is that you're using a earlier Ruby version than 2.0.

At the first line, you've defined the method with [keyword arguments](http://blog.brycekerley.net/post/46557214732/ruby-2-0-keyword-arguments). The error you've obtained is typically the one when working with an earlier Ruby version such as 1.9. The hash syntax 'size:' It's an unexpected syntax in a list of parameter in those versions.

In Ruby 1.9, you should define the method as following:

```
def user_profile_picture(user,  size=[50, 50], type=:square, style='img-polaroid', opts={})
  #...
end
```

Comment: in IRB, it works fine:
1.9.3-p327 :007 > {size: [50, 50], type: :square, style: 'img-polaroid', opts: {}}
 => {:size=>[50, 50], :type=>:square, :style=>"img-polaroid", :opts=>{}}

Comment: @Sudhakar But because you declare a hash not a method, it's not the same. I've seen your stacktrace, it's exactly what I obtain with Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 2.0, no syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @toch you were right. Using your code fixed the issue. Alos trying now to upgrade ruby to 2.0.0