# Ruby/Rails hash rockets Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, hashrocket

Can someone point me to a good primer just explaining the different syntactic features in Ruby/Rails? For instance, how come some examples I see do `myMethod(x: "z")` and others do `myMethod(:x => "x")`?

The syntax in general seems strange to me, just looking for a quick at-a-glance reference to use as a cheat sheet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004158/is-hash-rocket-deprecated?lq=1 && http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no?lq=1 && http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134702/ruby-1-9-hash-with-a-dash-in-a-key?rq=1 & many other posts about the same topic: "hash rocket syntax rails" in Google

Comment: Just with regards to your specific case, if I recall correctly the 1st way of doing myMethod(x: "z") was added into ruby 1.9 while before that the only way was to use the "hashrocket" and do myMethod(:x => "x")

Comment: here's a good general ruby sheet: http://overapi.com/ruby/  and @AlthafHameez is right about your specific question - the `x: z` syntax is just newer

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know what terminology to use to ask what these things mean.

Comment: Questions soliciting lists of links are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**They are the same**, it is just a matter of preferences.

I also asked myself *why would we add this new syntax if we already have one?* Well, Programming with Ruby implies that we are lazy and want to type the less possible caracters. So this new syntax allow us - lazy programmers - to write the same thing, minus 1 caracter!

---

But keep in mind some stuff, like the type of the keys for instance (Ruby 1.9.3):

```
> {a: 12}.class
 => Hash 
> {:a => 12}.class
 => Hash 
> {'a' => 12}.keys.first.class
 => String 
> {a: 12}.keys.first.class
 => Symbol
```

Also, some declaration are illegal with the new syntax:

```
> { '1-2' => "something" }
 => {"1-2"=>"something"} 
> { 1-2: "something" }
SyntaxError: (irb):38: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
{ 1-2: "something" }
      ^
(irb):38: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
```

For more informations: [Is there any difference between the `:key => "value"` and `key: "value"` hash notations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no?lq=1)

Comment: `MyModel.new(first_name: "Max")` seems to be illegal in a rails view (erb): `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'` using Rails 3.2.13. Or am I confused?

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.9.x or > ? This syntax has been introduced after Ruby 1.8

Comment: Ruby v1.8.7 - I feel like I'm missing the groundwork for Ruby/Rails. Sorry about that. I'm a life-long Java/C# developer and this is foreign/strange to me. :)

Comment: Okay, I see. A lot of examples use the `x: y` syntax but I'm just using an old version of Ruby! Thanks.