# Checking whether the json response is right or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I get a json response from my server.

```
{
    "@type": "res",
    "createdAt": "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
    "description": "test",
    "disabled": false
}
```

How can i test whether the `response` is `right` or `wrong`. Below is my test case.

```
it "can find an account that this user belongs to" do 
    Account.find(id: @acc.id, authorization: @token);

    expect(response.status).to eq 200
    expect(response.body).to eq({
      "@type": "res",
      "createdAt": "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
      "description": "test",
      "disabled": false
    })
end
```

When i try to execute the test, it throws me a lot of syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse `JSON.parse(response.body)`, because body as string:

```
it "can find an account that this user belongs to" do 
    Account.find(id: @acc.id, authorization: @token)
    valid_hash = {
      "@type" => "res",
      "createdAt" => "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
      "description" => "test",
      "disabled" => false
    }
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(valid_hash)
end
```

Or without parsing:

```
it "can find an account that this user belongs to" do 
    Account.find(id: @acc.id, authorization: @token)
    valid_hash = {
      "@type" => "res",
      "createdAt" => "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
      "description" => "test",
      "disabled" => false
    }
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
    expect(response.body).to eq(valid_hash.to_json)
end
```

Update, you `hash` syntax invalid instead:

```
 valid_hash = {
      "@type": "res",
      "createdAt": "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
      "description": "test",
      "disabled": false
    }
```

use:

```
 valid_hash = {
      "@type" => "res",
      "createdAt" => "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
      "description" => "test",
      "disabled" => false
    }
```

Comment: It stil says (SyntaxError) "@type" : "test"

Comment: I get a new error now... JSON::ParserError: A Json text must at least contain two octets!

Comment: Thanks it worked... how can i print response.body in my rails console to check...

Comment: upvote please if i help you, and [read about hash rockets in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835189/ruby-rails-hash-rockets-syntax)

Comment: I can't upvote as i need 15 votes it says... and also how to print response.body in rails console.

Comment: `puts(response.body)` before first `expect()` and look inside `log/test.log` or  from root dir `tail -f log/test.log` or use `https://github.com/pry/pry`